# Open interval $(a,b)$ is open in $\mathbb R$ but not open in $\mathbb R^2$ and $[a,c) (a<c<b)$ open in $[a,b)$ but nor open or closed in $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology

Open interval $(a,b)$ is open in $\mathbb R$ but not open in $\mathbb R^2$ and $[a,c) (a<c<b)$ is open in $[a,b)$ but nor open or closed in $\mathbb R$. $[c,b)$ closed in respect to $[a,b)$ but not closed nor open in $\mathbb R$.

What I'm having trouble with is how to look at the interval $(a,b)$ in relation to $\mathbb R^2$ and how can I make a ball centered in $a$ so $B_r(a) \subseteq (a,c]$ with respect to $[a,b)$ but not $\mathbb R$.

Comment: For the first question, I believe you are supposed to identify $(a, b)$ with $(a, b)\times\{0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. For the second, note that in $[a, b)$ with the Euclidean metric, if $r < b - a$, then $B_r(a) = [a, a + r)$, and if $r \geq b - a$, $B_r(a) = [a, b)$.

Comment: If you want to look at an interval $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, just draw a picture. Then, since your paper is similar to $\mathbb{R}^2$, try drawing balls with their centers in $(a,b)$. Can you give the ball a small enough radius to entirely be contained in the interval? You'll see that no matter how big the round ball you draw is, it will contain points not in $(a,b)$. Hence, $(a,b)$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question.  Let $c\in (a,b)\times\{0\}$. For any $\epsilon>0$, $(c,\epsilon/2)\in B((c,0),\epsilon)$ but $(c,\epsilon/2)\notin (a,b)\times\{0\}$. So no neighborhood of $(c,0)$ is contained in $(a,b)\times\{0\}$. Therefore it is not open.

For the second question, $a-\epsilon/2\in B(a,\epsilon)$ but $a-\epsilon/2\notin [a,b)$.  So, no neighborhood of $a$ is contained in $[a,b)$ and the interval is not open.  On the other hand, $B(b,\epsilon)\cap [a,b)\ne\emptyset$ for any $\epsilon.$  So $[a,b)$ is not closed either.